# grub rescue prompt

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, grubrescue

After 3 days of research and questioning the original owner of the Toshiba Satellite I have come to the conclusion I probably should give this up for something else, my son installed Ubuntu 10.4 on the Toshiba so that he could work from home a few days a week and now that he is full time and purchased a new computer I decided I would just use it for my work until one day I thought I would go back to Windows 7 ultimate and delete Ubuntu, well my mistake because there was no disc for either os and now all I see is "no such partition grub rescue>" every time I turn on the machine. I have put in commands that I have read would take me to the right partition but once I type in everything I still get the error message.

Typed in ls, got the message `(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (msdos3)` 
Then typed set `boot=(hd0,5)` then set `prefix=(hd0,5)/boot/grub` then set `root=(hd0,5)/boot`
At that point everything is good until I type `insmod normal` or `insmod linux.mod` then I get the error `"no such partition" grub rescue>`. Any suggestions on getting me back to Ubuntu or windows 7 without a disc or making a recovery flash drive, I'm down to my tablet and the option for downloading is out...thank you in advance I know I should have left well enough alone since I worked faster on this os than windows everyday

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid your best bet is to get a livecd/dvd.(Try asking a friend)

However if you anyhow manage to get back into Ubuntu you should reinstall grub by following thist tutorial:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair